# How do i fix SelectListItem does not contain a constructor that takes 3 arguments

Tags: asp.net, list

The Answers i saw on stack overflow didn't resolve my problem

```
<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleName, new SelectListItem(ViewBag.Roles, "Value","Text"), new { @class="form-control"})
    <a class="reset_pass" href="#">Lost your password?</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because SelectListItem has no constructors that accepts parameters. There is only an empty constructor. But your problem is different. you should create a [SelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlist.-ctor?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_SelectList__ctor_System_Collections_IEnumerable_System_String_System_String_) and not a SelectListItem. DropDowns are initialized with a SelectList made of many SelectListItems.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleName, new SelectList(ViewBag.Roles,  
                           "Value","Text"), new { @class="form-control"})
```